# Calculating Accumulated Value with C++

Tags: c++

I'm asked to write a program that reads in an investment amount, annual interest rate, and a number of years, and displays the future investment value using the following formula.

futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount x (1 + monthlyInterestRate)<sup>(numberOfYears X 12)</sup>
assuming that monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0.

However, I am not supposed to include any math libraries (which would have made things a whole lot easier, such as the `pow()` function).

My main issue is with the `accumulatedValue` property, where `(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate) * (numberOfYears * 12.0)` should be an exponent rather than just multiplication. I'm struggling to figure out how exactly that would work.

```cpp
// This is my code here

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double futureInvestmentValue;
    double investmentAmount;
    double annualInterestRate;
    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0;
    double numberOfYears;

    cout << "Enter investment amount: ";
    cin >> investmentAmount;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter annual interest rate in percentage: ";
    cin >> annualInterestRate;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter number of years: ";
    cin >> numberOfYears;
    cout << endl;

    double accumulatedValue = investmentAmount * (1.0 + monthlyInterestRate) * (numberOfYears * 12.0);

    cout << "Accumulated value is " << accumulatedValue <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have `(1.0 +monthlyInterestRate) + (numberOfYears * 12.0)` instead of `(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate) * (numberOfYears * 12.0)`

Comment: When dealing with presumably compound interest, exponents should factor in somewhere.

Comment: You're trying to calculate `monthlyInterestRate` before you know what `annualInterestRate` is. (Your initialization is not an equation that defines a relationship between values. Every expression denotes the value it has *right now*.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the OP literally says in the question that `pow()` is not allowed to be used.

Comment: @JamesHarden exponent is just another form of multiplication. Calculate `(numberOfYears * 12)` and subtract 1, that is your loop count. Then calculate `(1 + monthlyInterestRate)` and multiply that value by itself the calculated number of times in a loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer for various use-cases of your question.

## Answer with a whole number of years

You actually do not need the monthly interest rate at all, as

accumulatedValue = investmentAmount ×
(1.0 + 0.01*annualInterestRate)<sup>numberOfYears</sup>

Here, `annualInterestRate` is multiplied by 0.01, as you asked the user for a *percentage*.

With the assumption of whole years, the calculation can be performed as follows:

```
double accumulatedValue = 
    investmentAmount * 
    getGrowthFactorFor(numberOfYears, annualInterestRate);
```

with

```
double getGrowthFactorFor(
        int periods, double periodInterestPercentage) {
    double yearlyGrowth = 1.0 + 0.01 * periodInterestPercentage;
    double accumulatedGrowth = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < periods; i++) {
        accumulatedGrowth *= yearlyGrowth;
    }
    return accumulatedGrowth;
}
```

This is an exact answer, for as far as floating-point calculus is exact. Using a **double** will likely not represent any problems before the [United Federation of Planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets) is long gone…

This calculation is not very fast for a large amount of years, and you could replace `getGrowthFactorFor` with a faster algorithm, like [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) as suggested in [@chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182853/4121151).

If you do not need an exact answer, and you have a rather small combination of years and the interest percentage, you can also *approximate* the accumulated value in a single statement with

```
double accumulatedValue = 
    investmentAmount * 
    (1.0 + 0.01 * annualInterestRate * numberOfYears);
```

This uses the **power approximation** described below.

## Answer with a fractional number of years.

To do this, you can start with calculating the growth-factor for the whole number of years. Then you use the **power approximation** (below) to calculate the growth factor for the fractional remainder.

```
int wholeYears = numberOfYears;
double yearFraction = numberOfYears - wholeYears;
double growthFactorWholeYears = 
    getGrowthFactorFor(numberOfYears, annualInterestRate)
double growthFactorFractionalYears = 
    getGrowthFactorFor(1, annualInterestRate * yearFraction);
// Tada!
accumulatedValue = 
    investmentAmount * growthFactorWholeYears * growthFactorFractionalYears;
```

This is *not* an exact solution, but for, say 10% interest and half a year, you have the difference between a correctly calculated growth of 1,0488 and an approximated growth of 1.05. That's not even a percent off! And as the whole year calculation is exact, the final result is never far off from the actual value.

## Power approximation

If

- ε > 0
- *x* > 0
- *x* × ε much smaller than 1
- α is plus or minus ε

then

(1 + α)<sup>x</sup>

approximates

~ (1 + αx)

This is the first order Taylor approximation, but I won't bother you with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `for` structure to build the `pow()` function:

```
double pow(double base, double exponent) {
    if(exponent == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    double solution = base;

    for(int i = 2; i <= exponent; i++) {
        solution *= base;
    }
    
    return solution;
}
```

And now just use it in your program :)

NOTE: You're calculating monthlyInterestRate before getting the annualInterestRate. This may cause some problems, do it after the line `cin >> annualInterestRate;`

Answer (score 0):

With "not supposed to include any math libraries" and the exponent of the power is an integer, code could use a loop, but [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is often a better alternative.

```
// Power by squaring
double my_pow(double x, unsigned n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1.0;
  }
  double y = mp_pow(x, n/2);
  y *= y;
  if (n % 2) {
    y *= x;
  }
  return y;
}


double accumulatedValue = investmentAmount * my_pow(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12);
```

---

Given floating point details, this is also numerically more stable (less accumulated error, more monotonic).  If `n` was 1000, this is about 10-20 multiplications versus a loop of 1000 multiplications.